# resolv.conf overwritten *instantly*

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos, overwrite, redhat

In Scientific Linux 5.5, `/etc/resolv.conf` is continually overwritten and so DNS is broken. If I delete or change it, it *instantly* reverts to its former state. Writing over it with: `cp /etc/NEWresolve.conf /etc/resolv.conf && chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf` just results in an immutable copy of the original resolv.conf with no changes. I'm running as root (not sudo) and Avahi and NetworkManager are not running.

Any ideas? There's no DHCP anywhere on this machine, and even if there were, I can't imagine it'd overwrite the file so quickly.

Thanks

Some ancillary info:
uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.18-238.12.1.el5 #1 SMP Tue May 31 13:12:32 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Intel I340 (82580) NIC

Comment: what is the output of: lsof /etc/resolv.conf ?

Comment: lsof /etc/resolv.conf is blank

Comment: If you are at the console, try rebooting into single user mode and editing the file. If you still have the same problem, I suspect there may be a kernel module on your server that is doint this.

Comment: Single user mode worked. I made it immutable and the file remains untouched after reboot. Thanks a lot! Just for curiosity is there something specific you had in mind when you suggested that?

Comment: Check for a configuration management tool running like puppet, chef, or cfengine.

Comment: Are you running `resolvconf`?

Comment: A kernel module that modifies resolv.conf?  Incredibly unlikely.

Comment: I was thinking inotify, but was on my mobile at the time and couldn't think of the right word :)

Comment: I had the same problem with NetworkManager(NetworkMangler) rewriting it with crap from /etc/resolve.conf.d I ended up doing the chattr +i trick too.

Answer (score 2):

[NetworkManager](http://scientificlinuxforum.org/index.php?showtopic=461) is a likely culprit. NetworkManager will overwrite /etc/resolv.conf, and could explain the behavior you are seeing. However, I think NetworkManager typically adds a warning to the file like `# Managed by NetworkManager, do not edit.`

From the GUI, you can configure NetworkManager to not overwrite /etc/resolve.conf .

NetworkManager is considered harmful on many systems (Servers, virtualization hosts) because it overwrites your manual settings without warning you, and it doesn't support advanced networking features. You might want to to just shut down the service and prevent it from starting at next reboot.

Comment: If you really need NM you can mark interfaces as NM_CONTROLLED=no in their respective /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-* files. You can also set the nameservers there.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /etc -inum `ls -i /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $1}'`
```

and see how modifies the other files